# How to hide the datetimepicker after clicking on today button using bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am using https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails datetimepicker in my rails application. How do we close the widget after clicking on today button?

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', () => {

  $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
    timeZone: 'utc',
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss UTCZ",
    defaultDate: moment().tz('UTC'),
    icons: {
      today: 'todayText',
      up: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up',
      up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
      down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
      previous: " fa fa-arrow-left",
      next: "fa fa-arrow-right"
    },
    showTodayButton: true,
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    allowInputToggle: true,
    useCurrent: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch for the `dp.change` event, access the date picker through the data attribute of the anchor element, then call the hide function.

```
$(document).on("dp.change", () => {
    $(".form_datetime").data("DateTimePicker").hide()
})
```

Documentation Source:

- http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#hide
- http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange

Comment: I want to hide the picker only when "today" button is clicked. I believe this does for all change events. How do i achieve only for today button?